# Can we have Conditional UNION in a View in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I have created a VIEW which selects data from tables using UNION. I want to know if I can select the tables to be unioned based on the conditions.

If tableA.ColA = 1 then select ColA from tableA Union select ColB from tableB
Else
select ColA from tableA Union select ColC from tableC

Comment: Is this a single-row table?  If not, I'm not sure that I understand the logic you are trying to implement.  One row of `tableA` might have a `colA` value of 1, one row might not.  But in either case, your `UNION` would potentially return multiple rows.  Are you trying to transform each row in `tableA` to multiple rows in your result set?  Whatever you are trying to do, I'd suspect that you would want a pipelined table function rather than a view.

Comment: Yes I can potentially have multiple rows which is fine for me. Can I union tableA with tableB or C based on some conditions ? Never tried pipelined table functions but curious to know if there are any commonly used ways.. :) Thanks!

Comment: If you can have multiple rows, then I don't understand the results you want.  Posting an example of the data in the tables and the results you want is likely to be helpful.  Do you want to union `A` and `B` if any row in `A` has a `ColA` value of 1 and union `A` to `C` if there are no rows in `A` that have a `ColA` value of 1?

Comment: Yes.Union A and B if ColA meets a certain criteria else Union A and C.

Comment: But what if some rows in A meet the criteria and others don't?  That's why I'm trying to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please excuse my way of writing the comments.still learning to use stack overflow! So if tableA has two rows with colA as 1 and 0 values then the result should be two rows of tableA and rows of tableB else result should be the two rows of tableA and rows of tableC. Basically the view which I am trying to create should have either rows of tableB or tableC  based on the conditions provided.

Comment: All I am interested to know is the tables to be unioned can be conditionally selected. If yes can we do it in a view?if not in view then the next easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may want something like this where there are two branches of the query of which one is guaranteed not to return data because of the mutually incompatible predicates.

```
select b.*
  from (select ColA from tableA 
        Union 
        select ColB from tableB) b
 where exists( select 1
                 from tableA
                where colA = 1 )
union all
select c.*
  from (select ColA from tableA 
        Union 
        select ColC from tableC) c
 where not exists( select 1
                     from tableA
                    where colA = 1 )
```

As a practical matter, though, I would tend to question any data model that involved doing this sort of thing.  If you regularly need to union together data from different tables, that generally implies that your data model is incorrect.  For example, you may need an additional entity that is a parent of A, B, and C.  Or you may want to combine A, B, and C into a single entity with a type column that specifies whether a row is an A, a B, or a C.